# Python - Compare list of lists and pick biggest value

Tags: python, list, for-loop, compare, nested-lists

I have a list of lists:

```
l = [['a1', 2], ['a1', 3], ['a1', 1], ['b1', 4], ['b1', 2], ['b1', 6], ['c1', 2]]
```

I would like to compare each "sub-list" with the others "sub-lists", match those that have the same value for index `[0]` and just keep the ones that have the biggest index `[1]`, so that the result is something like this:

```
resultingList = [['a1', 3], ['b1', 6], ['c1', 2]]
```

I've been trying various for-loops and conditional statements, but I've got stuck.

Could someone give me a hand with this and put me on the right track?

Comment: show us your attempt(s)

Comment: Look at `itertools.groupby()`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby
l=[['a1',2],['a1',3],['a1',1],['b1',4],['b1',2],['b1',6],['c1',2]]
l = [max(g, key=lambda x: x[1]) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l), key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

Comment: no need to sort l, it seems already sorted. And if you sort it, no need to pass a lambda. Natural sort works fine here (that's minor)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I waffled on it, but I figured that there was no guarantee of real data looking as nice as the test data.  I'm not sure what you mean by "no need to pass a lambda".  It's my understanding that the default behaviour of `groupby` is to use the identity to generate keys, so wouldn't that fail to group `['a1', 1]` and `['a1', 2]` for example?

Comment: I misread, I thought `lambda` was inside the `sorted` function. I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Natural answer is using `itertools.groupby`, grouped by first element of the sublist, and simply apply `max` to each group. Since first grouped elements are the same, `max` naturally maxes according to second element: the integer.

```
import itertools

l=[['a1',2],['a1',3],['a1',1],['b1',4],['b1',2],['b1',6],['c1',2]]

print([max(v) for _,v in itertools.groupby(l,lambda x : x[0])])
```

result:

```
[['a1', 3], ['b1', 6], ['c1', 2]]
```

Note: if the list is not sorted according to first element values, `sorted(l)` needs to be used instead of `l`

Answer (score 1):

Make a dictionary to hold all the max values:

```
L = [['a1',2],['a1',3],['a1',1],['b1',4],['b1',2],['b1',6],['c1',2], ...]
d = {}

for k,v in L:
    d[k] = max(d.get(k, -float('inf'), v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the `lambda` expressions in @Patrick Haugh's solution by [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) like this:

```
In [18]: from itertools import groupby

In [19]: from operator import itemgetter

In [20]: l = [['b1', 2], ['a1', 2], ['a1', 3], ['c1', 2], ['a1', 1], ['b1', 4], ['b1', 6]]

In [21]: [max(g, key=itemgetter(1)) for _, g in groupby(sorted(l), itemgetter(0))]
Out[21]: [['a1', 3], ['b1', 6], ['c1', 2]]
```